# Sudo issue on AIX LDAP server

Tags: sudo, aix, ssl, ldap

When a user tries to sudo to root he recieves the error : 
ldap_start_tls_s(): Can't contact LDAP server.

What causes this problem?

Comment: Could be lots of things. Have you ruled out the ldap server? The network? Recent SSL changes on either the AIX or LDAP server?

Comment: This host is not supposed to use LDAP. Must be something on the client side creating this error. The user is locally created

Comment: Any tips on files that may be causing this?

Comment: Can you at least show the output of `lslpp -L "sudo*"` or `rpm -q sudo` depending on how you installed sudo? Also `sudo -V` output might help. Maybe you installed the ldap-enabled version of sudo but forgot to install some dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you have not provided enough details. The other unfortunate part is I do not have enough familiarity with AIX to know what utilities or what is used on an AIX system. I will give you examples based on Linux.

When you get `ldap_start_tls_s(): Can't contact LDAP server` errors, that is usually an indicator of a missing CA certificate or faulty configuration. You need to ensure your ldap.conf (whether that's /etc/ldap.conf, /etc/sudo-ldap.conf, etc) is configured properly. Here's an example of it configured properly on Linux.

```
uri ldap://ldap.example.com
ssl start_tls
tls_cacertdir /etc/openldap/cacerts
tls_cacertfile /etc/openldap/cacerts/cacert.pem
sudoers_base ou=SUDOers,dc=example,dc=com
```

This is the minimum you can get away with. The fact of the matter is you are more than likely missing a CA certificate, or there has been changes in certificates or CA's for the certificates for the LDAP server. You need to address this.

The other thing is, if your configuration is correct and your certificates are correct, you may also need a hashed symlink of the CA certificate. This is especially the case when using openldap utilities.

```
ln -s cacert.pem `openssl x509 -hash -in ca.pem -noout`.0
```

Comment: how do I omit this feature. This user is a local user and the server should not have ldap features running.

Comment: Modify /etc/nsswitch.conf appropriately by finding the sudo line. Make sure it only says sudo: files.

Comment: I don't  have this file on my machine

Comment: http://www.sudo.ws/man/1.7.4p6/sudoers.ldap.man.html